# How to uncheck rule in jcf-hidden add-on with selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, selenium

I'm doing automation for a website that is using jcf-hidden class (some kind of jquery class or something), and this add-on is setting the ability to get to the select element (the element that I want to get) as hidden/block.

But if I uncheck the `display: block !important;` so it works...

To test it, i added a wait element and uncheck it and saw that I could find the element.

How can I uncheck it from the code?

This is the checkbox i want to uncheck from my code:

[image]

I'm using scala by the way.

So the process i want is:

1. driver.get("https://go to the url i need where the dropdown is at")
2. Find the element

   val selectCompany = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("""//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/select[@id="company_id"]""")))

3.

```
//your solution here to uncheck the display: block
```

4.

Select a value for the element

```
  selectCompany.selectByValue("100")
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? it is not not clear

Comment: you see the button in the image I attached? I want to click on it when the page is loaded @MahsumAkbas

Answer (score 0):

you can run javascript to change attribute:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('company_id').setAttribute('style','display: block !important;')");
```

Comment: some people told me to do so, but no one is giving me a full answer. I'm very new to selenium and to programming in general, please try to be more precise for me